# Is there an option to debug MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, git, monodevelop

Is there an option (command line argument) to get debug information form `MonoDevelop` itself?

I have the following issue on `openSUSE` Leap 15:
When I try to open a project which is version controlled with Git, MonoDevelop crashes without error message. A workaround is to disable the add-in module Git.

Unfortunately the environment variables `MONODEVELOP_CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL`, `MONODEVELOP_FILE_LOG_LEVEL` and `MONODEVELOP_LOG_FILE` didn't work for me. The output is always empty. Only the time stamp of the log file changes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are developing an AddIn via the MHutch's MonoDevelop.AddinMaker, then yes you can run MonoDevelop from MonoDevelop and debug the AddIn. Do you have the Git addin source? Also if you are also working with the MonoDevelop source code within MonoDevelop, you can debug MonoDevelop.... Personally if you can just having a general Git Addin problem, disable the addin and use the git cmd-line to manage your local repo.

Comment: So, I cloned the MonoDevelop source from Gtihub and tried to compile the master branch. But I get errors with the external sources from libgit2:

Comment: `openssl_stream.c(36,3): error G08E93E1A: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘BIO {aka struct bio_st}; openssl_stream.c(94,1): error GC2E79D46: variable ‘git_stream_bio_method’ has initializer but incomplete type ;openssl_stream.c(94,19): error GC0CDC97E: storage size of ‘git_stream_bio_method’ isn’t known`